# Charging four cells in series with a TP4056

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, tp4056

[image: TP4056 Module]

I am using a [TP4056](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf) [module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEkYX.jpg) to charge four Li-ion cells in series using four of the modules.

The red wires in the diagram represent wires for positive terminals and black wires for the negative terminal, while blue wires and green wires are used for connections.

When I tried charging with this circuit the circuit burned out and the TP4056 and other components in the module started emitting flames and, obviously, the circuit failed to do what it was supposed to do.

Could anyone tell me the right circuit or changes I can make in the present circuit?

I have already considered problems like the circuit getting shorted or too much input and have taken care of that already, yet the circuit failed.

When tested with two cells in series it worked fine, but it failed with four cells.

[image: Charging Connection diagram]

Comment: As Bimpelrekkie says, you would need an isolated power supply for each TP4056 & cell combination. While this is not a usual method it is valid and the cells will charge to the same final voltage within the matching of the supplies.

Comment: How can I use the same power supply for each of the TP4056 and also not short the circuit? Will a resistor of 5K help if I apply it between the connections of - input terminal of each TP4056?

Comment: You can't, with the batteries in series. You could disconnect them completely from the series circuit, then you could charge them. But a proper charger for series cells would be much better and simpler.

Comment: @TusharDubey  You need to understand what you are being told and what makes it impossible in the manner you are trying. Each cell is at a different voltage above battery negative. The input charging voltage is ground referenced. The chargers  must be referenced such that charger -ve = battery -ve. Understand that and you will see why you need isolated charging supplies.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon thanks for your help and I appreciate the efforts you put to make understand the basic concepts of working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is **NOT** going to work!

The - input and - output of the TP4056 module are connected and that will **short your battery**. I have indicated one of the shorts in purple:

[image]

To be able to charge 4 cells in series with 4 TP4056 modules you would need 4 **separate, isolated** power supplies.

But I would not recommend that. The proper way to charge 4 cells in series is by using a charger that is designed for that task. It should include balancing so that all cells will be charged to the same voltage despite differences in capacity between the cells.

Comment: Just added schematic of this module if needed ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFSB5.jpg

Comment: What if we add a diod on each of the negative terminal of the input side