# Can I Charge 2 18650 with 2 TP4056 boards with single input

Tags: battery-charging, power-electronics, bms, tp4056

I found this video on youtube where they charges 2 18650 with 2 TP4056 modules with one input. below is the schematic he uses. Is it safe to do that?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Charging 4 cells in series with TP4056](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/542002/charging-4-cells-in-series-with-tp4056)

Comment: actually output is not connected so no short here and both batteries are in parallel . Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I would re-draw that "hookup" and made a **proper** schematic, it would look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFcnNJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note how this boils down to two batteries each charged by their own TP4056 module and the charger modules sharing the same 5 V USB supply.

This is perfectly fine!

Note how the batteries are **not connected to eachother**.

These batteries are **not** in series. A TP4056 module is not suited to charge batteries that are in series (I mention this in relation to your previous question where you meantion a 2s battery pack where the batteries are in series).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but that is only because the batteries have no connection to each other. That is just a charger for two separate batteries. The 5V supply also needs to provide enough current for charging two batteries.

it will not be safe circuit to charge a 2 cell pack where the two batteries are connected in series. It will short out one battery.